# Laravel5 Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-socialite

I've added

```
"laravel/socialite": "~2.0"
```

as a composer dependency, and i've added the service provider in my `config/app.php` just like this

```
'providers' => [
    // more providers
    'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider'
]
```

Then, when i access to any of my application route, i've got this `Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found` exception.

Looking into my `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` i see there's not the Socialite mapping - ive ran `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` more than once.

What's wrong?

Comment: I can say there's no error in the code - i've tried again removing references, running update again, then dump-autoload again, then re-enabling the provider, then dump-autoload again and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you run the composer command before adding the provider to the file? If not, this can sometimes cause issues.

I recommend removing the reference from the config file and the composer.json, then running `composer request laravel/socialite 2.0`. Also, just fyi, using the `::class` notation in the providers listing will help if you're using a full IDE like phpstorm, as it will highlight when it can't find the class.

Comment: The asker doesn't say what version of PHP he's running. `::class` is only available in >= 5.5. Hopefully they are running at least that, but I know most of our servers are still on Debian Wheezy and are still on 5.4 for that reason.

Comment: I know, the assumption was that they'd know about that. But, if they are using a proper IDE, if they were to attempt to use `::class` it would say that the current version of PHP doesn't support it.

Comment: Not necessarily. You have to set which version you're using in the settings of PhpStorm, otherwise I believe it defaults to what is installed on your system (my OS X has 5.5.27 installed, but I actually develop for 5.4.39 via Vagrant). Regardless, just wanted to make sure there was a note about that so others didn't use it without realizing

Comment: i think you mean `composer require laravel/socialite` right ?

Answer (score 2):

I have removed the reference from the config file and the composer.json, then ran composer require `laravel/socialite 2.0` instead of composer request `laravel/socialite 2.0.`

Then add the following lines to the config file

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all remove the line

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

and also

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

from Config\app.php and update the composer by adding 
`"laravel/socialite": "^2.0"` and after that add these two line in Config\app.php it will work because when you add these lines before updating composer it goes to vender folder and search for the SocialiteProvider but it is not available yet so when you will update composer first and then add these lines it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

At first of all, check if your socialite package is compatible with your Laravel version.

You can verify your Laravel version inside your Laravel path, for it type:

```
$ php artisan --version
```

Then, check in the socialite Git repository (link below) a compatible version with your Laravel.

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/releases

Now install the socialite package with `composer require laravel/socialite x.x` (where x.x is your socialite choosed version)

Lastly add the following lines in config/app.php file

inside    'providers' => [

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

and almost at the end of the file, inside 'aliases' => [

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Save the file.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to clear the cache of your project by this code

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and then you need to enter this code in the terminal (for facebook for example)

```
composer require socialiteproviders/facebook
```

in the previous line i ended it with facebook as an example but you could change it like  instagram or anything else and the error will be  solved